# How can I setup uWebSockets.js into existing KOA server?

Tags: node.js, websocket, koa, uwebsockets

I have an existing KOA server, and would like to use uWebSockets.js for a part of it (like chat functionality and other kind of direct notifications)

I see that uWebSockets.js can run as a standalone server, but it would be too much to rework the whole KOA server into uWebSockets.js. That is why I just want to place uWebSockets beside my http API, or just to replace the http part continuing using the ctx object and the koa-specific stuff:

```
const app = new Koa();

// ...here is some logic, DB init etc

// Here are my routes https://myapi.com/login https://myapi.com/getUser etc...
app.use(routers.routes());
app.use(routers.allowedMethods());

// IT would be nice to place the websocket somewhere here if possible, and to use some route like https://myapi.com/ws In best case it would reuse the existing DB connections etc...

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with Koa. They are different servers. You need to run a server on different port. You can do this within the same Node app to reuse db connections but this may result in less scalable app

Comment: @EstusFlask Thanks for the quick reply. Why the app may be less scalable? Do you have any example how could I integrate it in the same Node app? Thanks

Comment: Because this way servers are coupled and you won't be able to run 5 instances of Koa and 2 instances of UWS if there's a need for that. As for me, reusing DB connection isn't a sufficient reason to restrict app design this way.

Comment: Just paste the code for UWS into the app. The shouldn't be any other integration.

Comment: @EstusFlask Thanks, ít is not reusing DB connection, it is about reusing everything - helpers, authentication etc..

Do you mean just to start the UWS inside of one of the app.use would do the job?

Comment: "app.use would do the job" - no. They are totally different servers. UWS server is not related to Koa server. Their code shouldn't touch at all, you won't benefit from this. You start Koa with `.listen(...)` and UWS with `listen(...)` - this would be the same for any unrelated Node servers. You can reuse any existing project modules you need - helpers, anything. It's preferable for these servers to be started in different processes. E.g. Koa is `node app-foo.js` and UWS is `node app-bar.js`.

Comment: @EstusFlask Yeah, well it is not that easy to reuse the same logic. In KOA you have ctx, next, yeld, async await for everything. Many of the helpers are attached on the ctx. And I build around 100+ Routes already. It won't be that easy. Nvm thanks for the answer, I got the point - it is simply not possible to attach it like the koa-websocket reusing my current routes + extending it with the websocket.

Comment: I mean that models, etc units that aren't directly tied to Koa context can be used. You could implement middlewares similarly to koa-websocket, shouldn't be that hard, but I doubt this is practical, more likely will significantly reduce performance benefits of UWS.